# How to transfer values from a table in Microsoft word into a Intranet webpage textbox

Tags: textbox, transfer, intranet

I'm relatively new to javascript. But is there a way to How to transfer values from a table in Microsoft word into a Intranet webpage Text box, preferably using something simple like notepad to code? Also, is it possible to make it such that the transfer goes on even after the webpage goes on to page 2 and page 3 etc?

Comment: if possible you should post any code you have written to try and solve this problem yourself first. Then people will be more willing to help you.